# Accessing a service's promise from a route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am struggling to a Service's promised data in a Route. The problem occurs when I am transitioning to the Route at application init; that is, if I load the application, then transition, everything is fine, because the promise is already fulfilled, but if I hit browser reload on that Route, the offending lines won't run. The Service is:

```
// services/lime-core.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  resources: null,

  init() {
    this.set('resources', []);

    this.get('store').findAll('resource').then(resources => {
      this.set('resources', resources);
    });
  }
});
```

This service works perfectly in a template, assuming I have injected the service into the component. I access this service in the route as follows: (assume `slug` has a meaningful value)

```
// dashboard/route.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  limeCore: Ember.service.inject(),
  ...
  model(params) {
    ...
    this.set('resource', this.get('limeCore.resources').findBy('slug', slug));
    ...
  }
}
```

When the `model()` hook is called, the `limeCore` service's `init()` method is still waiting for the Promise to fulfill. I tried to be clever, but changing the code to something like:

```
this.get('limeCore.resources').then(resources => {
  this.set('resource', resources.findBy('slug', slug))
});
```

doesn't work, because `this.get('limeCore.resources')` does not return a Promise. This logic has to be in the route (i.e. can't be moved to a template), because I'm dependent on the slug value to determine an ID which loads a different set of ember-data.

Again, this code works properly once the Promise has been fulfilled — that is, on a future transition to this route, but not on initial application load.

I'm sure there is a correct way to do this... either the Service needs to return a Promise (while still being usable in templates), or I need to make sure that the Promise is fulfilled before the `Route.model()` method can be executed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question was poorly phrased, so I apologize to the reader for that. This happened because if I'm at the point of asking a question, it's often because I'm having trouble expressing the problem.

The approach suggested above didn't work for me, although it gave a few helpful hints. The significant requirement was that (as I mentioned in the comment) I needed to use the `resource.id` value in the model query. kristjan's approach addressed that, but my question didn't sufficiently show how complicated the model() method was.

An unwritten second requirement was that the ajax request is only made once, because the data rarely changes and is required in a lot of places on application load.

In the end, I was able to use a blend of kristjan's approach — creating a limeCore.getResource() method that loads the data in a Promise, and then require that promise in my route's `beforeModel()` hook. The key thing I realized was that `beforeModel()`, like `model()`, will wait until a Promise resolves before calling the next hook. In my application, `model()` should never run until these core objects have been loaded (`model()` is dependent upon them), so it made sense to have them loaded before. Perhaps there is a more elegant approach (which I'm open to hearing), but at this point I feel the issue has been resolved!

```
// services/lime-core.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  resources: null,
  clients: null,

  init() {
    this.set('resources', []);
    this.set('clients', []);
  },

  // getCoreObjects() needs to be called at least once before the resources, clients and projects are available in the application. Ideally this method will be called in the route's beforeModel() hook. It cannot be called from the application route's beforeModel() hook because the code will not succeed if the user isn't authenticated.
  getCoreObjects() {
    if (this.get('resources').length === 0 || this.get('clients').length === 0) {
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        resources: this.get('store').findAll('resource').then(resources => {
          this.set('resources', resources);
        }),
        clients: this.get('store').findAll('client', {include: 'projects'}).then(clients => {
          this.set('clients', clients);
        })
      });
    } else {
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({});
    }
  }
});
```

and in my route:

```
// routes/dashboard.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  limeCore: Ember.inject.service(),
  session: Ember.inject.service(),
  ...
  beforeModel(transition) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      return this.get('limeCore').getCoreObjects();
    }
  },

  model(params) {
    ...
    this.set('resource', this.store.peekAll('resource').findBy('slug', slug));
    ...
    return this.store.query('artifact', {'resource-id': this.get('resource.id')});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach i would use

```
app/misc/lime_core.js

function getResources(store) {
     return store.findAll('resource')
}

export { getResources };
```

random route

```
import { getResources } from 'app/misc/lime_core';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     const store = this.get('store');
     const sourcePromise = getResources(store);
   }     
})
```

But if you're still looking for service approach i would use it like this

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  resources: null,
  store: Ember.inject.service(),


  getResources: function() {
     return this.get('store').findAll('source')
  }
});
```

route

```
    limeCore: Ember.inject.service(),

    model: function() {
       const store = this.get('store');
       const sourcePromise = this.get('limeCore').getResources(); // sourcePromise.then(...

    }
```

" My route's model() method result depends on the id of the resource"

```
    model: function() {
       this.get('limeCore').getResources().then(sources => {
          return Ember.RSVP.hash({
               artifact: store.find('artifact', { source: source.get('firstObject.id)})
          })
       })
   }
```

Or solution 2

```
     model: function() {
           return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                   artifact: this.get('limeCore').getResources().then(sources => {
                       return store.find('artifact', {source: xx}) 
                  })
              })
           })
       }
```

Also your getResources function can be modified by your criteria

```
function getResources(store) {
         return store.findAll('resource').then(r => r.findBy('id', 1))
}
```

Comment: Although I haven't tried it yet (it's a bit late here), I'm not sure this approach will work. My route's `model()` method result depends on the id of the resource: `return this.store.query('artifact', {'resource-id': resource.id})`. How would the `model()` method return this follow-on query if it runs in a `then()` block?

Comment: Added solution for your problem, the question never stated that your facing a problem like this.

Comment: Hopefully you can generate your answer based on mine. Cant really tell your exact usecasse + no ember twiddle